Why are swimming goggles typically made from a different material than diving masks?
As discussed in this comment section, swimming goggles are typically made from polycarbonate, while diving masks are typically made from  tempered glass. Why are swimming goggles typically made from a different material than diving masks?

It comes down to strength requirements, weight and cost.
Diving masks need to be a lot stronger than swimming goggles, and tempered glass is the best way to do that. It is, however, a lot more expensive than polycarbonate, and significantly heavier, so for swimming goggles, which don't have the same strength requirements, polycarbonate is used.

Thanks! "Diving masks need to be a lot stronger than swimming goggles" why?

Total area under pressure leads to larger deformation in the faceplate of the mask. I would also suggest that optical quality is less important for goggles, particularly since they are so close to the eye lens. One expects them to scratch and they are cheap to replace.

A scuba mask is not under pressure - the inside is at the same pressure as the outside.  This is why scuba masks have to cover the nose - to give a pathway to add more air to the mask to maintain the internal pressure.  Scuba diving with swim goggles that don't cover the nose would cause eye damage by the time the diver was 10-20 feet down.

In fact when giving the issue a quick google, it seems that PC actually is considered "unbreakable" in this regard (but it is still a non-issue, as nobody seems to ever heard of a glass diving mask shattering). Maybe if you accidentally drop it on the floor, hitting some weird pointy thing, it may be an issue. People do report that glass masks scratch less, and fog less, so that may be reasons.

@AricTenEyck ideally that is true. But (having scuba dived) it is quite normal for there to be some pressure difference between inside and out (that you periodically clear using the nose).

@AricTenEyck 3 to 6 meters down? That doesn't sound like nearly enough, do you have a source for that claim?

@DonQuiKong You are right.  In the interest of Science and also Imaginary Internet Points, I did an experiment while scuba diving today.  As I descended, I plugged my nose to prevent air from getting into my mask.  At about 20 feet/6m, I began to feel mild discomfort in my eyes, and at 38 feet/11.5m, I was uncomfortable enough that I ended the experiment.  I didn't pop a blood vessel or anything like that, so I can say that the actual damage depth is probably more like 15-25m.

@RichardTingle that is true, but A) apparently tempered glass is more than strong enough and B) polycarbonate would actually be even stronger and not weaker than tempered glass.

The reason for different materials is different requirements between swimming goggles and diving masks.
First let's compare the properties of the materials:
Polycarbonate is cheaper, stronger and lighter than glass. It also protects against UV light.
Glass on the other hand is more scratch resistant and has better optical clarity.
Also glass works better against fogging up or the condensation doesn't impact the clarity as much, as it would on an polycarbonate mask. I can't really tell why, but that's the difference I noticed when switching from polycarbonate to tempered glass diving masks.
Now let's compare the requirements between swimming and diving. My opinion as vacation diver and former somewhat competitive swimmer / lifeguard with at least 2 trainings per week:
Swimming goggles need to be light for comfort. Optical clarity doesn't matter as they will fog up anyway and you don't care about looking on your surroundings while swimming. Because they fog up eventually and you can't / won't do anything about it, it doesn't matter if they fog up after 1 or 3 minutes.
You don't really look after them, you throw them without care in your bag or on the side of the pool. So they need to be robust, you don't want them to break. Because you handle them so carelessly you maybe even loose them or something breaks. You want them to be cheap to replace.
When swimming outdoors your head is exposed to the sun, UV protection is an benefit.
-> The benefits of tempered glass don't matter here.
When diving you want to experience the underwater world. Optical clarity is important. You don't want to clear the fog out of your mask often so the behavior there is important. While wearing the mask you're most likely deep enough under water where there is way less UV light. Diving trips for most divers typically don't have that daily routine feel as swim training for most swimmers. Most divers won't go diving 2+ times a week all year long, while that's the norm for swimmers. So diving gear gets less wear in the same time and is more likely to taken care off. It will last much longer and higher prices are more acceptable.

Does cleaning and maintenance factor into it too? I had a lot of trouble keeping polycarbonate googles from fogging after I once used soap to clean them (I'd seen soap used effectively for cleaning glass googles; didn't know any better). The fact glass googles can be easily made sparklingly clean might be an advantage?

@stevec the soap probably helped to wash away some factory applied ant-fog treatment. (it will always go away with time, but the soap accelerated it) Treating them again will help. Or just spit into them and rub it before using.

In addition to Rory and airace3's good answers, there are also the issues of construction and manufacturing.
Diving masks typically have large flat optical surfaces.  This allows the manufacturer to easily construct a mask using the optically superior glass.
Swimming goggles, on the other hand, are typically designed to reduce drag as much as possible.  Thus, only the front surfaces are flat, and the other surfaces are curved (forming a squat cylinder).  Using glass for the curved surfaces would add few benefits, but would significantly increase weight, cost, and manufacturing expense.
One could manufacture a swimming goggle with glass front surfaces, and plastic sides (those actually existed many years ago), but using a single material for the lenses reduces manufacturing costs and the opportunity for leaks.
